# change the profile to silent programmatically in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am trying to change the current profile of the phone to Silent. I am looking for the API to do this. These options are accessible via the Speaker icon on the main blackberry screen. 
How i can change the profile programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you can change the profile of  a blackberry device programatically. Sad but true

Comment: I guess it depends on your point of view. There are many valid reasons to want to change profiles automatically. Bedside mode will do this for you. On the other hand it isn't something I would trust to vary many developers to handle.

Answer (score 1):

It's currently **NOT** supported to change profile programmatically from normal to silent. Following are some links you might find useful.

BlackBerry Support Forums: [how to change profile programatically from normal to silent??](http://208.74.204.192/t5/Java-Development/how-to-change-profile-programatically-from-normal-to-silent/td-p/1236609)

blackberryforums.com: [Programatically Change Profile](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/4526-programatically-change-profile.html)

Answer (score 0):

I see this question in Blackberry Developer Zone;

> We **only** change the profile status(Means silent --> Loud like this) but we cannot change the **settings** (means you cannot change the slient's profile settings or Loud's profile settings);

see the sample code;

```
public final class LoadingScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener
{   
public LoadingScreen()
{        
    createGUI();
}

private void createGUI() 
{
    try 
    {           
        ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().launch("net_rim_bb_profiles_app");
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        //Exception
    }
}

public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context)
{

}   
}
```